# Phone wakes up a few minutes after every text message. Can I make that stop?

Tags: iphone

I have an iPhone 6S with the latest version of iOS. For a couple of months now whenever I receive a text message and put the phone back down it will wake up again for no apparent reason.

Sometimes it seem to randomly do so without a text message, but the text message one is reproducible.

Anyone have any idea why that might be and if I can stop it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Settings -> Notification -> Message -> Repeat alarm -> Never

Comment: Oh what on earth, why was that set to "once". Thanks! <3

Comment: @KitSunde "Once" appears to be the default. Mine was set to that too, and I'm pretty sure I've never even *seen* that option before.